# How do I rotate bones along bone axis?

Tags: armature

How do I rotate a bone along the bone axis? Nether the local or global help.[image]

Comment: Normal axis should work here

Comment: NO. I know that it is exactly 90deg.

Comment: I meant normal instead of global or local. It does not work for you?

Comment: I did find it. I did probebly forget to reed and did just see R>>R

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bone in edit mode has no rotation. And that probably why you cannot obtain a local axis coordinates.

But you can set the axis to "normal" and (for instance) use 'individual origins' as pivot point to rotate it around X or Z.

To rotate it around Y, use the roll value on the panel on the right.

[image]

You can do it with 'local' (or normal) axis in pose mode. It will work for X, Y and Z (no roll here).
Once done, apply the pose as 'rest pose':

[image]