# How do I set Roll=0 after setting a bone position/roll in edit mode

Tags: rigging, armature

When editing an armature, I would like to set roll=0 for a repositioned bone. See below.

[image]

Recalculate Role and Alt R are not resetting to bone roll value shown in the Transform panel... or I am applying them in the wrong mode? Trying Edit, Object and Pose...

Goal is to have bone orientation aligned to Z up, while at the same time the Transform Roll value is zero.

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74362/how-do-i-rotate-bones-along-bone-axis

Comment: Thanks... and I know I can cheat it... but there must be a way to reassign a bone's roll to zero... yes? I just sense I am missing something...

Comment: ... just set it to zero in the right panel? or do you mean something else?

Comment: Setting it to zero in the Transform panel at right rotates the bone... I want the roll I have set to "become" zero roll.