# Bone not rotating around local axis

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

So i have bone which i rolled and now i want to rotate it in pose mode around it's local axis but it is not rotating it around local axis.

I have looked at [this](https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23833) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74362/how-do-i-rotate-bones-along-bone-axis) but it is not working.
Why is this happening?

Here is image of setting it up:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this problem was to set these settings

[image]

And then when you press R(rotate) and then X > it will set rotation to global X axis but then X again and it will set to local one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the right side menu (press <kbd>N</kbd> if not opened), go to the Tool tab, and under *Pose Options* uncheck *Locations* (under Affect Only).